# Including node_modules css files not working in Webpack production

Tags: css, node.js, webpack

My code includes some CSS from `node_modules` like so

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import styles from '../css/SeekBar.css';
```

I'm importing the css file `rc-slider/assets/index.css` from the node_module `rc-slider`. This works in development with my Webpack config

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    include: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
  },
```

However in my production config, this does not work

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            module: true,
            localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: { plugins: postCSSConfig },
        },
      ],
    }),
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    include: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
  },
```

The error is below

```
   Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
           [0] ../~/css-loader?{"module":true,"localIdentName":"[path][name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"}!../~/postcss-loader?{}!../~/style-loader!../~/css-loader!../~/rc-slider/assets/index.css 988 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

        ERROR in ../~/css-loader?{"module":true,"localIdentName":"[path][name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"}!../~/postcss-loader?{}!../~/style-loader!../~/css-loader!../~/rc-slider/assets/index.css
        Module build failed: Unknown word (5:1)

          3 | // load the styles
          4 | var content = require("!!./../../css-loader/index.js!./index.css");
        > 5 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
            | ^
          6 | // add the styles to the DOM
          7 | var update = require("!./../../style-loader/addStyles.js")(content, {});
```

If I remove

```
 {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    include: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
  },
```

from the production Webpack config, there's no errors, but the styles are not applied from `rc-slider/assets/index.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: { plugins: postCSSConfig },
        },
      ],
    }),
    include: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app')],
    exclude: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: ['css-loader'],
    }),
    include: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
    exclude: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app')],
  },
```