# Styles imported from node_modules do not work on Vercel (but work on local environment)

Tags: css, next.js, vercel, uppy

I am importing [Uppy styles](https://uppy.io/docs/dashboard/#CSS) in my component. In the local environment styles are successfully loaded from `Uppy` module. But when app is deployed to Vercel then the CSS files are not loaded.

What am I missing?

```
import Uppy from "@uppy/core";
import { Dashboard } from "@uppy/react";
import "@uppy/core/dist/style.css";
import "@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css";

export default function UploadPage() {
  const uppy = new Uppy();

  return (
    <Dashboard uppy={uppy} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Possible solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255918/12749758](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255918/12749758)

Comment: @SatyamSaurabh but why? CSS from node modules support should work by default https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules

Comment: @SatyamSaurabh plus the package is deprecated https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeit/next-css

Comment: does it helps? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122471/12749758](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122471/12749758)

Comment: @SatyamSaurabh no